# VBA Code to loop through a start and and end date and only paste weekdays

Tags: vba

I have a code that I have written and its very basic so forgive me. In section 3, i need to basically autofill a date series but excludes weekends based on a start date and end date.

sh9 is the start date and sh10 is the end date so if sh9 was 10/12/2020 and sh10 is 10/22/2020, it would loop through but only paste weekdays for the 9 weekdays that occur between the two dates.

```
    '3. Same date, Start time to End time 1 by 1
    ws2.Range("BA" & rLoop + lr2).Value = ((sh9) + rLoop) + (Sh14)
    ws2.Range("BB" & rLoop + lr2).Value = ((sh9) + rLoop) + (Sh15)
```

Comment: Use the Workday() function to check the date before inserting it.

Comment: Sorry, the intention was to refer you to the `Weekday()` function as demonstrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code might look like:-

```
Sub WriteWorkdayDates()
    ' 107
    
    Dim Ws2             As Worksheet
    Dim MyDate          As Variant
    Dim EndDate         As Variant
    Dim R               As Long             ' row number
    Dim C               As Long             ' column number
    
    Set Ws2 = ActiveSheet
    R = 9
    With Ws2
        MyDate = .Cells(R, "SH").Value
        EndDate = .Cells(R + 1, "SH").Value
        If IsDate(MyDate) And IsDate(EndDate) Then
            C = Columns("BA").Column
            Do
                MyDate = MyDate + 1
                If MyDate > EndDate Then Exit Do
                If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(MyDate) <> vbSunday And _
                   WorksheetFunction.Weekday(MyDate) <> vbSaturday Then
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = MyDate
                    C = C + 1
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

On review I find that I misunderstood your variables `Sh9` and `Sh10`. Please feel with me on this subject because the same thing will happen to you when you review your code a year from now. That's why they always recommend to give "meaningful names". However, once you get used to my fetish for avoiding syntax intended for addressing ranges for the purpose of addressing cells you should find it easy to bend my code to your intentions.